# Define exceptions from global pgfplotsset settings

Tags: pgfplots

I am using the following code in the preamble to set the position of my axis labels:

```
\pgfplotsset{
    every axis y label/.style={at={(-0.1,0.5)},rotate=90}
}
```

I have roughly 10 plots, where this settings is correct and what I actually want. But for a single other plot I would like to set the position differently. Is is possible to set a specific option to ignore the global setting and define a local exception? Something like:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
overwrite axis y label/.style={at={(-0.2,0.5)},rotate=90}
\end{axis}
\addplot[...]
\end{tikzpicture}%
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use `every axis y label/.style` for that `axis`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
    every axis y label/.style={at={(-0.1,0.5)},rotate=90},
    width=6cm
}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ylabel=thing]
\addplot {x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
ylabel=thing,
every axis y label/.style={at={(-0.2,0.5)},rotate=90}]
\addplot {x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ylabel=thing]
\addplot {x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

In my documents, I usually have the following in the preamble:

```
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
  line width=.6pt,
  tick style={line width=0.6pt,black},
  grid style={line width=0.6pt,dotted,gray}}}
```

If I now just write

```
\begin{axis}[%
grid style={line width=6pt,dotted,gray},...]
```

within a figure this will overwrite the predefined setting.

Comment: any idea how to override a "no marks" style?

Comment: Nevermind, "only marks" seems to re-enable marks.